# How to change css styling for different lines within a paragraph in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code that defined a variable called circles, and appended it a title. The title has four lines, first is the country, second is the price, 3rd is the value, and 4th is the gdppc. 
Now I want to make the gdppc a larger font size than the previous 3 variables. This would require me to style gdppc separately from the others (currently they are all styled by this css called tipsy). However, I don't know how exactly would I do that.

```
circles.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.country + "<br/> " + "Price=" + d.trust 
        + ", Value=" + d.business + "<br/> " + d.gdppc; }); 

$(".circles").tipsy({ gravity:'nw', html: true,});
```

The idea is probably to make gdppc a separate variable, and style it separately. How is this implemented in coding?

I tried

```
var ratings = function(d) {return d.gdppc};
circles.append("title")
            .text(function(d,ratings) { return d.country + "<br/> " + "Price=" + d.trust 
            + ", Value=" + d.business + "<br/> " + ratings; }); 
$(".circles").tipsy({ gravity:'nw', html: true,});
$(".ratings).myownstyle({});
```

and it doesn't work, probably because of I am an amateur who doesn't understand anything about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it:

```
circles.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { 
        return d.country + "<br/> " + "Price=" + d.trust 
          + ", Value=" + d.business + "<br/> <strong>" + d.gdppc + "</strong>; 
    });
```

CSS

```
strong {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

**Note:**

You could use any tag here, `<span>`, `<em>` and/or you could use classes to hook the style to them, rather than just adding a css rule to the element.